# drupal module_list on every page load

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In my devel query info I see module_list being run on every page.

This should not be right?

I feel like there's a whole bunch of incorrectly ran queries being run on my site, (there's some unidentified problem), and this is the function that stood out to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used during bootstrap meaning it's run on all pages. Normally it will just return a static variable, but during bootstrap it'll need to run a query to build the variables..

Drupal uses it to find out which modules you have installed, so it's a very essential function.

Comment: Worth noting that development may be what is causing the cache to clear on every request.

Comment: So if it shows up in the devel's querylog then it's bad right? I'm not purposefully clearing the cache, and afaik there's no development going on.

Comment: It needs to run once per page load, development or no.